# Appixia on magento CE 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, appixia

I need to develop Magento cart plugin on Appixia Api for mobile app. I have gone through the documentation on Appixia knowledgebase. Appixia only have Prestashop cart plugin. So I want to know how to get started in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent initiative!

To help you get started, I uploaded a skeleton to github. It's a working Magento extension with some basic capabilities. It was initially developed for version 1.6.2.0.

The source code is [available here](https://github.com/appixia/cartapi-plugin-magento).

Github is the largest open source repository in the world. You can easily clone this project to your own github account (they're free). Once your work is ready for sharing with others, you can even push your contributions into the "official" Appixia repository where everybody could find it.